In Oracle Apex's Gantt Chart, Can I Implement Drill Down Functionality
**I want to Implement Drill Down Functionality in Gantt chart in Oracle Apex 19. is it possible. I mean if user click on any gantt, user will redirect to that data in the below interactive grid or somewhere other page with report?

I don't think this is possible out of the box. There is no "Link" attribute in Gantt chart series (link attrbitue is available for other types of charts like bar chart).
